# How to migrate SearchSite in Django-Haystack from 1.X to 2.X?

Tags: python, django, django-haystack

So I've been reading [the migration docs](http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/migration_from_1_to_2.html) and I'm stuck at

> • The removal of SearchSite & haystack.site.
>  • The removal of
>   handle_registrations & autodiscover.
>  • The addition of multiple
>   index support.
>  • The addition of SignalProcessors & the removal of
>   RealTimeSearchIndex.
>  • The removal/renaming of various
>   settings.

because, "Removal of `RealTimeSearchIndex`" is described, however what to do in place of `autodiscover` and `SearchSite` I can't find in there. Does anyone know where to look/what to do? I'm stuck with how to migrate `SearchSite` primarily.

Answer (score 0):

I have to migrated in some sites and I allways followed this steps:

***Remember to save your Index or Indexes using a backup, snapshot or any other way***

1. Uninstall **ElasticSearch**
2. Uninstall **default-jre-headless** *(In case you have it installed, it's good to update java)*
3. Uninstall **pyelasticsearch** and **django-haystack**
4. Install **openjdk-7-jre-headless**
5. Install new **elasticsearch** (I use 1.3.4).
6. Install with **pip** **django-haystack==2.3.0**, **pyelasticsearch==0.7.1** and **elasticsearch==1.2.0**

*Usually I had openjdk-6-jre-headless installed and I update it to openjdk-7-jre-headless*

With this 6 steps I updated many projects to **Haystack 2.3.0**

You can try with other software versions, I've used these and works fine

Comment: Thanks, but it's more the syntax changes that I need assistance with. There are a number of terms that have changed syntax for django-haystack 2.X, and I'm trying to find the syntax for those.

Comment: I've read some changes in the official docs about the changes on `SearchSite` but it didn't affect any of the projects I work, after the update to Haystack 2.3.0 everything still works. Sorry I couldn't help!

Answer (score 0):

See my caveats in your other question...

I'm not sure if there's an easy autodiscover replacement to save typing. You may have to just list out all your search index classes and their fields of interest instead of letting haystack slurp up all your models.

The migration doc says that indexes.Indexable is a little mixin class you'll need to add/inherit. It should basically just flag the class as something haystack should care about. This should basically take the place of explicitly calling register on your models. You'll also need to have a get_model method on your search index classes -- I believe this ties them to whatever django model you are messing with. The index_queryset method doesn't seem mandatory based on the docs (http://django-haystack.readthedocs.org/en/latest/searchindex_api.html#index-queryset) but may be of interest depending on what the "whole" set of data means to you when you reindex things. HTH.